# Obter dados de geolocalização através do Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

Existe alguma função ou biblioteca no Python ou Java que interaja com o Google Maps e seja capaz de trazer as coordenadas de geolocalização de smartphones que estejam com o GPS ativo?